# Arduino 4G LTE Shield

Tags: shields, gsm, networking

Is there by any chance a shield that can take an 4G LTE compatible SIM card activated by a carrier and establish a connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Googling "4g shield arduino" gave [this](https://www.cooking-hacks.com/4g-gps-3g-gprs-gsm-gps-lte-wcdma-hspa-shield-for-arduino). It will need a 4G LTE capable SIM, but I guess "it depends" if *any* 4G LTE SIM will work..

Answer (score 1):

This is a really old post but I also found [this LTE shield](https://www.botletics.com/products/sim7000-shield) which is much cheaper than the cooking hacks one.

Be carefully; this module is a dual band only (900/1800 MHz); no 850 or 1900 MHz.